# Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not working on both admin and frontend

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

I have Magento 2.1.9 installed on my cPanel shared hosting account. Everything worked fine until I asked my hosting provider to run the necessary commands during Tawk.to chat integration. The commands he ran made my site to display blank pages.

I managed to get the site back online by running the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade php bin/magento

php setup:static-content:deploy

bin/magento cache:flush

chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Even though I can now access my site, but the CSS formatting and JavaScript in both the admin panel and frontend don't work.
 See how my admin panel looks like:
[image]

**Please note:** in line 607 of the app/etc/di.xml file, I had already changed the following content:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

to:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

What else can I do to fix this issue?

Be advised that I set the file permissions for the directories below to 777.

```
/pub/

/pub/static/
```

The following directories have 775 permissions:

```
/pub/static/frontend/

/pub/static/adminhtml/

/pub/static/_requirejs/
```

What are the proper file permissions those directories? 755 or 777?

Please, I'd really appreciate your time and insight in helping me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of js and css not loading is most probably due to the improper static content deploy. Please try deploying your individual locale wise.

For eg:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU en_US

Run

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

before running static content deploy just to make sure your previous content gets removed.

Hope this will help. If it does, don't forget to accept my answer and vote up.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Sure, I won't forget to give you credit, if it works out. How do I ascertain the locale of the site?

Comment: In the admin >> Stores >> Configuration >> Local Options >> Locale is set to English (United Kingdom). Does that mean the proper locale is en_GB or en_UK?

Comment: the whole site went blank, after running the commands using 'php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB'

Comment: Please deploy for en_GB en_US, because most of the file are taken from US locale. Do php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US

Comment: Thanks, but I have just reinstalled Magento.